# How to check if view is added in a feature?

Tags: views, features

For Drupal views is there any way/field which tells us if your view is added to a feature or not. And if yes in which feature it is added?

I have a view which I need to check if it is added in a feature or not.I have lot of features on my site and I am searching all the features one by one to check if the view is added in any of them. Is there any other efficient way to check this?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) export views' code in files like this: `my_module.views_default.inc`. Every feature module with a file `my_module.views_default.inc` contains views.

**Manually:**

Searching against those modules by using the view's machine name as an input, will show whether that view machine name is tracked or not, to any of these modules.

**Using drush:**

Having all your features updated `drush fu-all -y` do some changes to a view (save) and `drush fl`. The feature that will appear with an `overridden` status contains that view, otherwise the view is not tracked yet. To see which features contains views code do `drush fc --exported` and select `views_view`, that will narrow down significantly the searching range.

[More Features & Drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/960926)